# STDERR PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Customer::isOwnStudents()

Tags: php

> [STDERR] PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method Customer::isOwnStudents() in /upload/catalog/view/theme/Super_green/template/common/header.tpl on line 62

header.tpl looks like

```
<?php
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
if($this->customer->isOwnStudents()>0) echo $orderfood;
echo $language . $currency . $cart . $konto;`}
?>

class ModelAccountStudents extends Model {  

public function isOwnStudents() {
        $results = $this->getStudentses();
        if(sizeof($results)>0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

What is wrong here in this code. I do not know why do I get this err.

Comment: It looks to me that isOwnStudents() is a function of the ModelAccountStudents class. Where is $this->customer defined and is it an instance of ModelAccountStudents?

Comment: I am trying to find Customer class, its not easy.

Comment: Just try searching your code for "class Customer". Are you using an IDE?

Comment: I found Customer class and made necessary changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it looks like `$this->customer` is an instance of `Customer` - you've defined the `isOwnStudents()` method for the `ModelAccountStudents` class, not the `Customer` class.

Comment: I am trying to find Customer class, its not easy.

Comment: I found Customer class and made necessary changes.